# ObjectContext.Attach generates incorrect entity key

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using .NET 4.0 with EF POCO's. I have a conceptual model from which a part is shown in the image. Everything works fine, except one thing which I have been almost busy with for 2 days and still don't get it to work!

In my conceptual model, a WebShop can have one or more related WebShopCategory instances. Each WebShopCategory associates a WebShop with a Category and enables me to specify additional properties for a WebShop/Category combination.

See image here: http://postimage.org/image/djrn4xh37/

When creating a new WebShop instance of course I need to save it, which I do in an Update method of a WebShopRepository which uses the EF ObjectContext as shown in the code below:

```
using (MyEntities entities = new MyEntities()) {
    if (webShop.ID == 0) {
        entities.Countries.Attach(webShop.Country);

        foreach (PaymentMethod paymentMethod in webShop.PaymentMethods) {
            entities.PaymentMethods.Attach(paymentMethod);                    
        }

        foreach (QualityMark qualityMark in webShop.QualityMarks) {
            entities.QualityMarks.Attach(qualityMark);
        }

        foreach (WebShopCategory category in webShop.Categories) {                
            entities.Categories.Attach(category.Category);
        }

        entities.WebShops.AddObject(webShop);                    
    }

    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

One thing to note is that all related items already exist in the data source. As they are not yet in the ObjectContext, I've attached them before adding the created WebShop to the ObjectContext. This seems to work as expected: all entities that have been attached have an EntityState.Unchaged state which is correct. The added WebShop is in the Added state which also is correct.

However, it can happen that when I attach the Category instances (category.Category) EF gives an exception stating that there is already an item in the object context with the same key. I have found this ObjectStateEntry instance and what I noticed was that the EntityKey only consists of the EntitySet name, and not with the ID also in the key. Other EntityKeys that have been added to the context are all in the form of `EntitySetName;ID=value`

To me it seems that the entity key is somehow not being determined correctly by the EF, because at the point where it goes wrong I've checked and made sure that the added category is indeed valid: it is a category already known in the sytem and has its primary key (ID) value set to 1 (which is the first added category in the system).

I've tried many ways to fix this but cannot get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you all very much in advance!